# gcc error for `int y=&x`

Tags: c, gcc

gcc gives `error: initializer element is not computable at load time` for (bad type):

```
int x;
int y=&x; /* bad type */
```

but gcc compiles this fine (only `*` type declaration added):

```
int x;
int *y=&x;
```

What part of `&x` is not computable at load time? (Any cast in 1st src for gcc to compile?)

---

Edit: turns out gcc (v7 linux amd64) compiles this src, why? (change `int` to `long`):

```
int x;
long y=&x; /* bad type */
```

Edit2: gcc 32-bit compiles first src with `int`. I guess type coercion not done at compile-time?

Edit3: it is **a given** that unnecessary type "coercion" is bad src

Comment: `&x` is x's address, thus a pointer to int : however in your source, `y` is an int. Assigning an `int*` to an `int` will result in a warning from your compiler, so this looks perfectly fine.
Also, you should use `uintptr_t` to store pointers, not `int` or `int*`.

Comment: What version of GCC are you using? This is a strangely bad error message, reminds me of the old days.

Comment: @DeiDei gcc 8.1 gives the same error message for file-scope `x` and `y`.

Comment: why long y=&x; compiles by gcc?

Comment: Please read answers and previous comments. A `long` is the same size as a pointer so 'casting' it to a pointer works. It is not recommended though.

Comment: so this is platform dependent, where `int` is not same `sizeof` as pointer. thx

Comment: `long y=&x;` compiles in GCC because GCC accepts lots of non-standard code as an extension. `long y=&x;` is not valid C. Use `-pedantic-errors` to make GCC to generate hard errors for invalid code.

Comment: @in, worked on too many ancient cpu where `int` was **native** `sizeof` pointers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason `long x = &y;` does not get the error message about a value not being computable at load time is that the target executable file format has provisions for resolving addresses. That is, there are commands and data that the compiler and linker can put into the object files and executable files that say “When you are loading this program into memory and have chosen the starting address for the section containing symbol y, put y’s address in location x.” This is how the compiler makes `long x = &y;` work: It tells the loader to do it.

The reason that `int x = &y;` does get the error message is that this command to put the relocated address into x will not work in this case. In this case, the `int` x is too small to hold a full address, so the compiler would need a command that says “Take y’s address, chop off the high bits, and put the low bits in x.” The loader does not have any command that does that, so the compiler reports that the value cannot be computed at load time.

Now we can see why `int x = &y;` does not get the error when a 32-bit mode is used: A 32-bit address will fit into a 32-bit `int`. It is trying to put a 64-bit address into a 32-bit `int` that is a problem.

Answer (score 2):

In `int y=&x;`, `&x` is a pointer to an `int`. You cannot store a pointer in an `int` variable. The solution you have in your question is correct.

EDIT: **Why does `long y=&x;` work?**

It works probably because a `long` is big enough to hold a pointer on your machine. **However**, gcc should give you a warning about this by default. Run gcc with `-Werror` to prevent it from accepting this code.

Comment: Although you shouldn't really use `int *` to store pointers, but `(u)intptr_t`.

Comment: As I see it, `typedef`ed pointers aren't such a good idea in C, because it's not so clear that they need to be freed.

Comment: @GregoireLodi,turns out `int` fails on gcc amd64 but did compile on 32bit. thx

Comment: @GregoireLodi: You really should use pointers to store pointers. gcc is lamentably lax about mixing pointers and integers. If you want to store a pointer value in an integer, you *must* use a cast.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what the error message is, but it has to do with the fact that an integer variable can't be set to an address. You should not use `int y = &x`, since that statement just doesn't make any sense. You should only assign addresses to pointer types.